# load dll error while using System.loadLibrary()

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I'm making a program use JNI to call some native directives. My code is:`System.loadLibrary("poc_NativeShellExecutor");`

When I run the code, I got the exception:

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no poc_NativeShellExecutor in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)`

I check the `java.library.path` and I'm sure I do put the poc_NativeShellExecutor.dll in C:\Windows\System32.
Here is some info of my system:

```
Java version: 1.7.0_03, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: E:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: GBK
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

Could u please give me some help?

Comment: So what *exactly* have you set `java.library.path` to? If you haven't set it, Java will use `PATH`; does that actually include the `system32` directory?

Comment: The `Program Files (x86)` folder implies that you're using a 32-bit JVM on a 64-bit OS.  Is your `poc_NativeShellExecutor.dll` a 64-bit DLL?  If so, you'll either need to recompile it, or else switch to a 64-bit JVM: a 32-bit process cannot load a 64-bit DLL.

Comment: Ernest, the system32 directory do exists in the PATH variable.

Comment: Daniel, poc_NativeShellExecutor.dll is a 32-bit DLL.My jdk is a 32-bit version.

Comment: try loading using absolute path `c:\windows\system32\yourdll.dll`

Comment: @JigarJoshi u mean `System.load("c:\windows\system32\yourdll.dll")`?I've tried this way, didn't work then.

Comment: Set `-Djava.library.path="<path to your native libraries>"` from your JVM options or `System.setProperty("java.library.path","<path to your native libraries>")` in your code. You can append as many paths as you want but put `;` in between the paths (for Windows). This affects per-JVM rather than globally.

Comment: @eee I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. Actually, I find a solution in another topic. I put the DLL in the root directory of my project, then run `System.loadLibrary("poc_NativeShellExecutor");`. I works and no error occurs.

Comment: @eee Actually, putting native libraries under application path is what I normally do and it is my preferred way. It works all the time. I don't like to meddle with OS's system folders.

Comment: @NigelWu: Have you tried using a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to ensure that any transitive dependencies (other DLLs that your DLL loads) can be found and that there are no linkage errors there?  The Windows `LoadLibraryEx` function will often report that there's an error loading a DLL when in fact the error had to do with one of its dependencies.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks a lot, I tried Dependecy Walker and find some errors while loading my DLL.They r some incompatible problems between my 32bit DLL and the 64bit sys DLL. But what's strange, my program could work fine with the DLL in it's root path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the solution, but additional data, that I hope can help to find one.

I have the same issue as the OP.

My system is `Windows7 Ultimate x64 SP1`.
I run my 32-bit `test_x86.dll` using the 32-bit jvm 1.6.0_29.

I've tried to place `test_x86.dll` in the following folders:

```
C:\
C:\Windows
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

and it works: my `test_x86.dll` is successfully loaded.

But if I place my dll into

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no test_x86 in java.library.path
```

I change my `java.library.path` each time before trying to load the dll, so it always starts with the corresponding directory:

```
java.library.path = C:/;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin; ...
java.library.path = C:/Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin; ...
java.library.path = C:/Program Files (x86);C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin; ...
java.library.path = C:/Windows/System32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin; ...
```

I also tried to use the default `java.library.path` (that contains `C:\Windows\System32` by default) with `test_x86.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32`. No luck: it also leads to the exception above.

I always have the single copy of `test_x86.dll` in folders that are in the `java.library.path`, i.e. only one of the folders contain that file at a time.

### Conclusion:

It seems that in Windows 7 x64 the `C:/Windows/System32` have some tricky restrictions.

Earlier on my Windows XP 32-bit machine, I never warried about `C:\Windows\System32` folder and `java.library.path` changes. I've simply used the `System.loadLibrary("test_x86");` call with `test_x86.dll` in that folder, and it always worked.

Comment: +1, just had to say thanks for sharing this. Who would have though System32 would be a bad place for libraries?

Comment: The problem is C:\Windows\System32 would be for 64-bit DLLs. If you put test_x86.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 it would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to C:\Windows\System32 on a 64-bit Windows from a 32-bit application, Windows actually searches in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. You would have to place the dll's for 32-bit applications there.